# how to have 4 columns in a row simpleform SAPUI5

Tags: css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to align columns in `<form:SimpleForm>`. I need 4 columns in a row but only 2 columns are aligned. Here is my example, Please refer [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/feyijo/edit?html,output)

**Needed output :**

label input-field  label input-field

**current output :**

label input-field

label input-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm with Two Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216940/sap-ui-layout-form-simpleform-with-two-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a new container on the right, simply set an empty title.

But be aware tabbing won't be from left to right, top to bottom but (per container) top to bottom, left to right
After all, it just a SimpleForm ;-)

See this working example (please run the example **full-page**, otherwise it will still show the fields top-town because of the responsive nature):

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function() { }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
      xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
        <f:SimpleForm
            maxContainerCols="2"
            editable="true"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                labelSpanL="4"
                labelSpanM="4"
                emptySpanL="0"
                emptySpanM="0"
                columnsL="2"
                columnsM="2">
            <f:content>
                <core:Title text="A Title" />
                <Label text="1st label" required="true" />
                <Input value="Blah" />

                <core:Title text="" /> <!-- empty title so it looks like this container belongs to the left one -->
                <Label text="2nd label" required="true" />
                <Input value="Blah" />
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```