# Responsive Form with multiple columns?

Tags: sapui5

I defined the following simple form:

```xml
<form:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormChange354"
  editable="true"
  layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
  title="Address"
  labelSpanXL="2"
  labelSpanL="2"
  labelSpanM="3"
  labelSpanS="12"
  adjustLabelSpan="false"
  emptySpanXL="0"
  emptySpanL="0"
  emptySpanM="0"
  emptySpanS="0"
  columnsXL="2"
  columnsL="2"
  columnsM="1"
  singleContainerFullSize="false"
>
  <Label text="Name1"/>
  <Input/>
  <Label text="Name2"/>
  <Input/>
  <Label text="Name3"/>
  <Input/>
</form:SimpleForm>
```

As you can see:

[image]

How to place the red marked element next to *Name1* element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to enable multiple columns, the property `column*` or the `<layoutData>` aggregation should be adjusted respectively in (Simple)Form.

## Using `ColumnLayout`

[As of v1.56](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/5e3c12dd3890894e2762bc8cf22c45fbd106832c), the new layout `sap/ui/layout/form/ColumnLayout` can be assigned to (Simple)Form which enables "a newspaper like style" without the need to insert any Titles, Toolbars, or any additional layout data to have multiple columns.

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], async Fragment => {
  "use strict";

  const control = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<form:SimpleForm xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns="sap.m"
      title="Multiple Columns via ColumnLayout"
      editable="true"
      layout="ColumnLayout"
      columnsM="2">
      <Label text="Label 1"/>
      <Input/>
      <Label text="Label 2"/>
      <Input/>
      <Label text="Label 3"/>
      <Input/>
    </form:SimpleForm>`,
  });
  
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

In case more adjustments are required, the [layout data `sap/ui/layout/form/ColumnElementData`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.form.ColumnElementData) can be assigned. E.g.:

```xml
<Label text="Label 3">
  <layoutData>
    <form:ColumnElementData cellsSmall="3"/><!-- default: 12 -->
  </layoutData>
</Label>
```

#### Resources

- [API reference: `sap/ui/layout/form/ColumnLayout`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.form.ColumnLayout)
- [Test Page for `ColumnLayout`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/layout/form/ColumnLayout.html) (source code can be found [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.layout/test/sap/ui/layout/form/ColumnLayout.html))

## Using `ResponsiveGridLayout`

<sup>**Not `ResponsiveLayout`** as that is [deprecated](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/eb8c174ef28c3a31b21e74e96b204340dabd5e5c) as of UI5 v1.93. `ResponsiveGridLayout` is still supported.</sup>

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], async Fragment => {
  "use strict";
  
  const controls = await Fragment.load({
    definition: `<core:FragmentDefinition
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
      xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
      xmlns="sap.m">
      <form:SimpleForm
        title="Multiple Columns via GridData"
        editable="true"
        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
        <Label text="Label 1">
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L2 M2"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L4 M4"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="Label 2">
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L2 M2"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L4 M4"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Input>
        <Label text="Label 3">
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L2 M2"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Input>
          <layoutData>
            <layout:GridData span="L4 M4"/>
          </layoutData>
        </Input>
      </form:SimpleForm>
      <form:SimpleForm
        title="Multiple Columns via Containers (columns* + sap.ui.core.Title)"
        editable="true"
        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
        columnsM="2">
        <core:Title text="Container 1"/>
        <Label text="Label 1"/>
        <Input/>
        <core:Title text="Container 2"/>
        <Label text="Label 2"/>
        <Input/>
        <Label text="Label 3"/>
        <Input/>
      </form:SimpleForm>
    </core:FragmentDefinition>`,
  });
  
  controls.map(control => control.placeAt("content"));
});
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

#### Resources

- [API reference: `sap/ui/layout/form/ResponsiveGridLayout`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout)
- [API reference: `sap/ui/layout/GridData`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.GridData)