# Label not in the same line with text in OpenUI5

Tags: xml, layout, sapui5

I have a `Form` with layout:

```
<f:layout>
          <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
           labelSpanXL="4" labelSpanL="4" labelSpanM="4" labelSpanS="4"
           emptySpanXL="1" emptySpanL="1" emptySpanM="1" emptySpanS="1"
           columnsXL="2" columnsL="2" columnsM="2"
           singleContainerFullSize="false" />
 </f:layout>
```

then in `FormContainer` I have a label with text:

```
<f:FormElement>
        <f:fields>
            <Label text="text">
            </Label>
            <Text text="label">
                <layoutData>
                    <l:GridData span="XL1 L4 M5 S4" />
                </layoutData>
            </Text>
        </f:fields>
</f:FormElement>
```

and it looks awful - label is not in the same line with text (line is higher, see below the screenshot)
[image]

why is that so? Why it's not in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing it wrong. As per the [API Reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Select/controlProperties), you can define the label for fields in formElement and what you are trying is defining label as another field in the formElement.

You can try the following code:

```html
     <f:FormContainer title="Form title">
         <f:formElements>
          <f:FormElement label="Email">
           <f:fields>
            <Text text="EMail" />
           </f:fields>
          </f:FormElement>
          <f:FormElement label="Teleephone">
           <f:fields>
            <Text text="Tel" />
           </f:fields>
          </f:FormElement>
          <f:FormElement label="SMS">
           <f:fields>
            <Text text="Sms" />
           </f:fields>
          </f:FormElement>
         </f:formElements>
        </f:FormContainer>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: you know, yea, it works but then I have a problem with adding it into two columns and as I saw in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217896/4952262 there is a chance to add label and text independently

Comment: @Michu93 The [mentioned samples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217896/5846045) are using `sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm`. [SimpleForm](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm) is a syntax sugar for `sap.ui.layout.form.Form` which simplifies adding labels and form elements.

Comment: I agree with @Boghyon here.

Comment: Actually I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236935/4952262 but it's not intuitive.

Comment: @Michu93 Nothing is intuitive in UI5. There, I said it. After all these years.